# ¿Cómo contar el número que se repite una secuencia?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basándome en este código, quiero contar el número de veces que se repite una secuencia, por ejemplo cuantas veces , salen 2 rojas seguidas, 3 rojas seguidas, 4 rojas seguidas y así hasta 20, ¿Qué tendría que modificar?

```
import random
import time


apuestas_ganadas = 0
apuestas_perdidas = 0
max_ganadoras_consecutivas = 0
max_perdedoras_consecutivas = 0

bolas = []
bolas_rojas = [
    1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36
    ]


ganadoras_consecutivas = 0

while True:
    bola = random.randint(0, 37)
    print(f"Nueva bola: {bola}")
    bolas.insert(0, bola)
    print(f"Bolas: {bolas}")

    if bola in bolas_rojas:
        print("Roja!")
        apuestas_ganadas += 1
        ganadoras_consecutivas += 1
        if ganadoras_consecutivas > max_ganadoras_consecutivas:
            max_ganadoras_consecutivas = ganadoras_consecutivas


    time.sleep(3)
```

El resultado que deseo sería algo similar a esto:

```
Rojas 1 vez seguida: 2034 veces
Rojas 2 veces seguida: 1004 veces
Rojas 3 veces seguida: 504 veces
Rojas 4 veces seguida: 101 veces

etc..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrias que incrementar en 1 el contador del numero maximo de consecutivas cada vez que sale una bola no ganadora

```py
import random
import time


apuestas_ganadas = 0
apuestas_perdidas = 0
max_ganadoras_consecutivas = 0
max_perdedoras_consecutivas = 0

bolas = []
bolas_rojas = [
    1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36
    ]

resultado = {}
ganadoras_consecutivas = 0

for _ in range(10000):
    bola = random.randint(0, 37)
    bolas.insert(0, bola)

    if bola in bolas_rojas:
        apuestas_ganadas += 1
        ganadoras_consecutivas += 1

    elif ganadoras_consecutivas:
        resultado[ganadoras_consecutivas] = resultado.get(ganadoras_consecutivas, 0) + 1
        ganadoras_consecutivas = 0 


for i in sorted(resultado.keys()):
    print(f"Rojas {i} seguida: {resultado[i]} veces")

# Rojas 1 seguida: 1282 veces
# Rojas 2 seguida: 603 veces
# Rojas 3 seguida: 322 veces
# Rojas 4 seguida: 136 veces
# Rojas 5 seguida: 79 veces
# Rojas 6 seguida: 28 veces
# Rojas 7 seguida: 15 veces
# Rojas 8 seguida: 11 veces
# Rojas 9 seguida: 3 veces
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto! gracias